# erro Javascript, behavior/general.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

tenho o seguinte erro acusando no modo desenvolvedor do navegador

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function general.js:1549
init general.js:1549
(anonymous function) login:542
c jquery.js:4
p.fireWith jquery.js:4
x.extend.ready jquery.js:4
q
```

não encontrei nada que me ajudasse e minha aplicação se comporta de maneira estranha.

**Atualização**

código em haml da página

```
%a{:href => "http://www.site.com.br"} © 2014 empresa
%script{:src => "js/jquery.js"}
%script{:src => "js/behaviour/general.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
```

função no arquivo .js que o erro aponta:

```
if(config.select2){
    $(".select2").select2({
        width: '100%'
    });
}
```

Comment: André sem ver o seu código não podemos ajudar mais do que traduzir essa mensagem de erro para PT...

Comment: ah sim, desculpe. só um minuto

Comment: André, o select2 precisa de um ficheiro .js como este: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.2/select2.js. Não vejo ele na sua lista a ser carregado depois do jQuery...

Comment: tudo estava no diretório errado, com chamados errados, estou tentando implementar um template de administrador e minha aplicação, porém ainda não descobri como se faz.